# Why use JsHelper for jQuery integration?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I was trying to integrate jQuery to use it for some effects in my site and I started to search for the solution of integrating in the best way. It simply came to my mind to write a helper which would get the selector of proper element and output the javascript code.
Then I ran into the new JsHelper in cake 1.3 but I'm really having problems understanding the concept of JsHelper. I mean for sure each JavaScript block that I'm gonna write is more than one call to jQuery methods and many of them are also not transfered to JsHelper. So for what reason may I use the JsHelper? it would be much easier to write the javascript specified for my action inside a helper and use it simply as any other helper. The only thing which comes to my mind as a good capability is to use the caching and buffering options provided in JsHelper nothing more. Did I understood the JsHelper well or I have missed some points?

Comment: Nobody says you have to use the JsHelper. Ive never used it, opting instead for plain js files like a normal app. Im not a fan of using php to write the js.

Comment: It works great for the Ajax pagination, no thinking needed at all, but other than working  with CakePHP components, any custom stuff you may as well write yourself.

Comment: yes I can, and I'm doing but I wanted to ask if there is any other reasons using it. right now I write my own helper which sends the needed js code to JsHelper buffer and then outputs it at the end of HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, I never use any of the javascript helpers except to write the include, i.e.

`<?php echo $javascript->link('aJavascriptFile') ?>`

I'd be pulling my hair out trying to find out why some jQuery plugin wasn't working if it was all wrapped up in helpers.

You don't have to use helpers - they're there to help. Sometimes people go a bit crazy and start creating helpers for stuff that really doesn't justify the weight of extra code.

Just code it the 'old way' and keep your sanity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think this would be the wright way too.

Comment: Me too, I've never used the js helpers, and I'm glad to find that I don't seem to be missing out on much.